# OpenGL 2D colors gone wrong

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am having problems with my simple 2D OpenGL game.
Its really weird, I get textures to display correctly etc. but when I wanted to create particle effect with simple changing colors, for some reason it displays wrong colors from the buffer. I am using Android's OpenGL ES 1.1 but its the same with any version of OpenGL that uses VBO's.

I initialize the screen etc. and red triangle is displayed, but according to my color buffer it should be white, whats wrong?

```
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
        gl11.glLoadIdentity();
        gl11.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0f, 0f, -container.getCamera().getScale(), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f);
        gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl11.glTranslatef(container.getCamera().getX(), container.getCamera().getY(), 0.0f);

        container.addParticle(new ColouredParticle(-container.getCamera().getX(), -container.getCamera().getY(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), 0f, 5000));

        particleColorBufferPointer = createFloatBuffer(gl11, GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, new float[] {
                1f, 1f, 1f, 1f,
                1f, 1f, 1f, 1f,
                1f, 1f, 1f, 1f,

        });

        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particleColorBufferPointer);
        gl11.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        particleVertexBufferPointer = createFloatBuffer(gl11, GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, new float[]{
                -0.1f, -0.05f,
                0.1f, -0.05f,
                0.0f, 0.05f
        });
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particleVertexBufferPointer);
        gl11.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        gl11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        gl11.glDeleteBuffers(2, new int[]{particleVertexBufferPointer, particleColorBufferPointer}, 0);

        gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl11.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        int error = gl11.glGetError();
        if(error != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.v(TAG, "error " + Integer.toHexString(error));
        }
```

Its just simple hardcoded float array containing the triangle vertices and colors, but for some reason the colors are wrong as I said before, what can possibly go wrong with such small amount of code? the color doesn't change to anything but black, like it only reads the red value from the buffer. Also it gives absolutely no error at all!

createFloatBuffer method:

```
private int createFloatBuffer(GL11 gl, int type, float[] data) {
    int[] bufferPointerBuffer = new int[1];
    gl.glGenBuffers(1, bufferPointerBuffer, 0);
    int bufferPointer = bufferPointerBuffer[0];
    gl.glBindBuffer(type, bufferPointer);
    FloatBuffer dataBuffer = createFloatBuffer(data);
    gl.glBufferData(type, data.length * FLOAT_SIZE, dataBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(type, -1);
    return bufferPointer;
}
```

Comment: The bind for the color data must use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` since it's not vertex data.

Comment: @StefanHanke: `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is only for indices, why do you think it applies to colors? I don't believe that's correct.

Comment: @Tim: Oops misread the documentation. Sorry!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, that is certainly strange. Where does this function `createFloatBuffer` come from, I'm not familiar with it?

Comment: added the code of it to the main post, but it can't really be the problem, as it works for everything else, textures and so on..

Comment: What happens if you specify 3 floats/vertex? I know it's a long shot, but it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.. It all was because I had texture bound and it for some reason tried to draw it even if I had texture coords disabled, I wish i could have just listened when I got told to disable any state thats not needed anymore.. Thanks guys! Problem solved!

Comment: Well, to be precise, binding the texture (through `glBindTexture`) doesn't do any harm, as long as you disable texturing (with `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`).